# pulling object/array by value json vs arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

The scenario is an ajax request fetches a json response which contains a product_id among other values in each object, I already have a php variable which contains an array of product objects (laravel collection) so I don't want to pull these again adding another join to my query and slowing things down.

So I have 2 options as far as I can see either write my phone object to a json object stored in a js variable or as an associative array. The problem is the only way I can see of accessing the data I need i.e product.make product.name is by running a for loop on either the array or the objects whilst looping through the each object of the json returned by the ajax request so a nested loop which isn't ideal.

My question is, is there a way to pull just the object or array needed by a given keys value? Sorry if that's not very clear, it was the best way I could explain it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to accomplish this:

```
$map = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$array_of_keys = array('b', 'd');

var_dump(
    array_intersect_key( $map, array_flip($array_of_keys) )
);

/*
array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(4)
}
*/
```

Comment: Sorry I need to do this in javascript as I am working with a json ajax response and can't pass js to php only php to js